# How to override the open command in terminal for folders?

Tags: terminal, finder, defaults

I am using alternative file manager (specifically [Marta](https://marta.sh/), but this could be any file manager like fman or Forklift) and I would like it to open folders when I run the `open path/to/dir` command from the terminal. I'm running Big Sur 11.5.1.

I tried running `defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string org.yanex.marta` but it doesn't work. I also looked for the "open with" option in the "Get Info" menu but it's not available for folders. What did I miss?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231950/default-application-to-open-folders-with) question discusses a similar problem but the author asks to remove the default app (Path finder) rather than set it.

Comment: So basically you want to have `open FOLDER` open this folder in your alternative file manager? Would a shell function help?

Comment: Yes, `open FOLDER` would open it with the alternative file manager but I still want to keep the functionality of the `open`command for files (i.e. opening with the default app)

Comment: How can you call the file manager from the command line so it opens a folder?

Comment: It doesn't have a cli interface. I can use the `-a` option of the open command to force it to use the alternative file manager.